# Why do I have to specify my address in my WCF configuration (it is actually working)

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have set up a wcf service and when I browse to the .svc file I am presented with a screen that says...

> You have created a service.

So I know that the service is running successfully. However I have looked in the configuration and it does not actually have an address.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CountryProvinceBehavior" name="CountryProvinceWCFService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ICountryProvinceWCFService" behaviorConfiguration="CountryProvinceBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="CountryProvinceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="CountryProvinceBehavior">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

I then wrote a console app to test the service.

I got thr url from the browser and added a 'Service Reference' from a console application I was expecting the project to create enpoint defintions in my configuration file. And then when I create a client I could load up one of these configs but they aren't there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *have to* specify the address in configuration, although in this case you do specify the address for the endpoint (""). That means that WCF will use it as an address relative to the service *base address*. If the service is hosted in IIS, then it'll be the address of the .svc file. If the service is self-hosted (i.e., using `ServiceHost` directly), then the address will be the one passed to the `ServiceHost` constructor.

Comment: yeah but why wont visual studio create the enpoint configurations for the client when I add the reference?

Comment: Your service uses webHttpBinding / webHttpBehavior - which is a binding for REST (i.e., non-SOAP) services. Unlike for SOAP endpoints, there's no metadata exposed in the REST case, so the "add service reference" wizard cannot create the client configuration correctly (sometimes it even creates something, but in the vast majority of the cases, the client it creates cannot be used directly to consume the service).

Comment: Why is there no metadata exposed for WCF services? Surely we should be able to call them from a c# client app? Or do we just manually create POST requests and parse the documents have returned?

Comment: There's no metadata for *REST* endpoints. You can definitely call them from client apps, but you won't be able (at least as of .NET 4.0) to create a proxy using Add Service Reference. What people usually do is to either share the contract between the client and the service, and then you can create a proxy using something like `WebChannelFactory<T>`, or for simple requests often classes such as WebRequest / WebClient are used as well.